# Matching a regular expression without capturing the whole thing

Tags: c#, regex

I need to parse a text file for certain information. I am using a regular expression to do so. My question is, is it possible to match an expression but only capture a relevant part, negating the need to strip the unnecessary characters after capture?

Comment: You can use *capture groups* for that.

Comment: Take a look at [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), and also [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Looking into those now, thanks guys.

Comment: Sorted, thanks again.

Comment: Although the suggested duplicate is for R and not C#, the syntax of the regular expression itself is likely to be the same, or at least very similar. There are [a lot of other possibilities here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=capture+part+of+a+string+regular+expression).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, google "regex capturing groups" or check this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#named_matched_subexpression